# where is the client-side EaselJS file?

Tags: easeljs

Here is (more or less) the text in a sample script tag for EaselJS:

'script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js">

Note the file name: easeljs-0.8.2.min.js
But...when I download EaselJS from GitHub I can't find the equivalent file. The closest I can come is this: easeljs-NEXT.min.js.

I want to point to a client-side script, so that I can work off-line. Like this:
"script src='easeljs-0.8.2.min.js'' /script"

In the downloaded files from GitHub, which file is the correct one to point to in the src attribute for local use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone to https://code.createjs.com? There are links to download all the versions of EaselJS libs.

You can also get the latest compiled libs in the [lib/](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/lib) folder on GitHub, or download any of the releases here: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/releases